# Split a cube in z-axis using borders

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D-array e.g, `A = rand(3,5,10)` and I want split it in the `z-dimension` using specific **borders** stored into a matrix, e.g, `borders = [1 2;3 5;6 10]` to get a new matrix (**cell**):

`B = {A(3,5,borders(1,:)), A(3,5,borders(2,:)), A(3,5,borders(3,:))};`

Can we do this using a built-in function, i.e, without `for` loops?

**EDIT:**

```
B = cell(1, length(borders));
for i=1:length(borders)
    B{i} = A(:,:, borders (i,1):borders (i,2));
end
```

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if it helped you. The same with your other questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `borders` directly as a index and then use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to break it into a cell array where each element is `[1 x 1 x size(border, 2)]`.

```
B = squeeze(mat2cell(A(3,5,borders),1,1,ones(size(borders,1),1)*size(borders,2))).';
```

The squeeze and transpose are really just to get it to be *exactly* the same shape as yours, if you don't care about the shape of the resulting cell array you can simply do.

```
B = mat2cell(A(3,5,borders),1,1,ones(size(borders,1),1)*size(borders,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If its not important, that B is a 3d array, this should produce the same result:

```
reshape(A(3,5,borders(:)), size(borders))

ans =

    0.1419    0.7060
    0.4898    0.3500
    0.0759    0.4173


squeeze(B)

ans =

    0.1419    0.7060
    0.4898    0.3500
    0.0759    0.4173
```